# babel-runtime module not found when using material-ui-pickers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, brunch

i have a react project built using brunch. I am now trying to use `material-ui-pickers`, by just trying the very first example:

```
// Imports
/* eslint-disable */
import MuiPickersUtilsProvider from 'material-ui-pickers/utils/MuiPickersUtilsProvider';
// pick utils
import MomentUtils from 'material-ui-pickers/utils/moment-utils';
```

And wrapping the whole app:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
   <App />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

I am having the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/get-prototype-of' from 'material-ui-pickers/utils/MuiPickersUtilsProvider.js'
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "brunch-app",
  "description": "Brunch.io application",
  "private": true,
  "author": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "brunch watch --server",
    "build": "brunch build --production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^1.0.0-rc.11",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.2",
    "react-redux": "~5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "~3.7.2",
    "shortid": "^2.2.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "auto-reload-brunch": "^2",
    "babel-brunch": "~6.1.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "~6.24",
    "brunch": "^2",
    "clean-css-brunch": "^2",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^4.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.6.1",
    "hmr-brunch": "^0.1",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "^2"
  }
}
```

I haven't found much info, the only thing was about installing `babel-runtime`, which i did but did not work.

Thanks.

Comment: IIRC I had a similar issue in the past, I fixed it by playing with babel-* packages versions, someway I fixed it by upgrading them... never really understand what was going on.
What I see: you are using a very old version of babel-preset-env, maybe your version of babel-core is also old?

Comment: Thanks @LucaFabbri ;-) i will have a look !

Comment: Nothing to do, i updated to the latest version but still not working.

Comment: any luck on this? I'm seeing this as well when we upgraded to 3.2.2.